# Tumblr html code for photoset won't fit the pictures?

Tags: html, tumblr

i've been scavenging the internet for about 3 hours now trying to fix my tumblr theme's coding for photosets. My problem is, is that the themes original coding for the photoset doesn't allow the photos to fit in the borders of the post. I've tried changing the px to the 700px, 500px, 400px, and 250px, but none of them work for it, the photos are still cut short. I've looked here on other stackoverflows for a solution to this but i couldn't find anything. Something that caught my eye is that the layout for it is a little different than other themes photosets, as well as what it says

```html
{block:Photoset}
{block:IndexPage}
</center>
 
<div class="heart">{LikeButton color="black"}</div>
<div class="hov"><a href="{reblogurl}" target="_blank" ><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/zxmtfvb/etRnicft6/befunky_screen_shot_2014-07-22_at_5.png.png" title="{notecountwithlabel}"></a></div>
 
{Photoset-250}</center>
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
<center>
{Photoset-500}</center>
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Photoset}
```

this is the piece that is in my theme for the photosets layout.

i really don't know what to do with it because i've done all i know.

I don't know much about coding but maybe a different part of the html needs to be changed along with this part, but i don't want to mess anything up so that's why i'm coming here for answers.

Here is the theme i am using http://pastebin.com/AWyYscup

And here is my blog so you can see what i mean by the photosets being cut short
tri-0.tumblr.com

I'd really appreciate if someone more knowledgeable on the subject could help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `{Photoset}` instead of `{Photoset-250}`. It will create a responsive photoset that shrinks to fit the container